# Qt Creator : how to get gcc warnings with a project using Visual C++ compiler?

Tags: qt, gcc, visual-c++, qt-creator

I have a C++ project using cmake and Visual-C++ compiler.

Though I'd like to make a *fake* compilation with gcc just to get the warnings of the gcc compiler. This will fail to link because it has to link with external Visual-C++ binary dependencies, but I just need the compilation errors/warnings, not the link part.

Is there a way in Qt Creator to run such a *fake build* on the fly without changing my CMakeCache ?

Comment: You could presumably make it build somewhere else? E.g. have build/visual and build/gcc folders. Depending on the kit selected, you would build in one or the other. You should be able to do that in "Build Settings" in the projects tab, and create a different build configuration for each.

Comment: Oh right, we can set different kits on the same projects, I guess that would work thx !